# Why does NuGet package reference incorrect .NET framework/standard?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, mqttnet

tl;dr:

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project consuming a NuGet package which supports .NET Standard 2.0. That package, in turn, requires another package which supports .NET Standard 2.0.  However, when run, the latter package uses `net461` binaries rather than `netstandard2.0`.

**How do I force a NuGet package & its dependencies to use .NET Standard 2.0?**

**Are there special steps required to consume a .NET Standard package from a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project?**

Specifics:

I am trying to get the NuGet package for `SparkplugNet` (which uses the `MQTTNet` package) working in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project - just the basic ["How to use" SparkplugB example](https://github.com/SeppPenner/SparkplugNet/blob/master/HowToUse.md).  Both projects support .NET Standard 2.0.  After some debugging (details below), it appears `MQTTNet` is trying to use code paths specific to .NET Framework 4.6.1, rather than .NET Standard 2.0, and crashing with no feedback whatsoever.

To troubleshoot, I built `SparkplugNet` and `MQTTNet` from source.  As far as I can tell, the crash comes from hitting .NET 4.5/4.6.1-specific code in `CrossPlatformSocket.ConnectAsync()`, specifically this line ([in context](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/d2ce9d607a0058d53bc46bb594b6af44e9a1925c/Source/MQTTnet/Implementations/CrossPlatformSocket.cs#L199)):

`await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginConnect, _socket.EndConnect, host, port, null).ConfigureAwait(false)`

When I debug, `_socket` is a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` which doesn't appears to have a `BeginConnect()` method, at least in the source file my debugger pulled.  I am not sure why it branches to that code when .NET Standard 2.0 would be a better fit.

Back to a 4.7.2 project consuming `SparkplugNet` & `MQTTNet` via NuGet package....  If I look at the reference paths, `SparkplugNet` is properly pointed at the `netstandard2.0` folder, but `MQTTNet` points to `packages\MQTTnet.4.1.3.436\lib\net461\MQTTnet.dll`.  If I change the hint path manually in the project file, MSBuild appears to pull from the `netstandard2.0` folder, but it still crashes.  I assume it is the same cause, though I'm having trouble debugging using NuGet packages.  Also, I'm hoping for a better solution than hacking hint paths.